# mutt or mail - reply to or from email

Tags: email, centos6, mutt

When running either the "mail" or "mutt" command, how do I set either the "reply-to" or "from" email address such that:

- When the user clicks "reply", it goes to that email
- The user can see the email they will be replying to in the "from" box

I have tried the following so far:

```
mail ... -S replyto="<email>" - clicking "reply" chooses correct email, but cannot tell until click "reply"

mail ... -r <email> ... does not work at all, it seems

( export REPLYTO="foo@bar.baz"; mutt .... ): same as mail -S above
```

The important thing is doing it from the command line, NOT from the configuration files.  Every email we send out could have a different person that we need them to reply to.

Comment: turns out my manager is fine with the first option, using -S replyto="<email>".  I thought he wanted to change the way "From" appeared as well, but turns out he wanted "From" to stay old email and just to help users if they ignore text of email and click "reply" by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that long time ago I did look for this and I ended up using mailx

```
cat somefile|mailx -r "noreply@example.com" -s "important msg" destination@example.com
```

Comment: Ahh, in my case, mail and mailx are the same ( mail ends up being a softlink to mailx ).  So must be my version of mailx.  I also suspect maybe -r is being ignored if settings and config is setup a certain way.

Comment: Checked and it's a link for me also.
I did just test with "mail" and -r works just fine there also so it's not that it behaves different depending on invocation.
On a fedora 27 system I execute
  "echo test 1|mail -r "noreply@example.com" -s "test1" <me>@<my domain>"
and then the email header contains
  Return-Path: <noreply@example.com>
  ...
  From: noreply@example.com

Comment: If  anyone is wondering, that mail -r works on some machines, not on others.  I expect it is something with my Postfix settings.